# Distribute Shapes or PageElements via the Google Slides API?

Tags: google-slides-api

How can the Google Slides API be used to do the same as the "Distribute" function which is available from the GUI editor?

(as in:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly achieving it, yet. But as a workaround, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve the position of each objects, that you want to arrange, using the get method. 2. Calculate each rearranged position. 3. Arrange each object using ``updatePageElementTransform`` request of the batchUpdate method. But the selected objects on a slide cannot be retrieved using Slides API. Please be careful this. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you! I'll just find a way to proceed differently.